# All pairs of records from two tables oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, permutation

I need to find all unique pairs (not permutations) of records between two tables. The following gives me all permutations of `A`, `A_1`:

```
with a1
as(
select
'abc' as a,
1 as dummy
from dual

union all

select
'efg' as a
1 as dummy
from dual)

select
a1_1.a,
a1_2.a
from a1 a1_1
join a1 a1_2 on a1_1.dummy = a1_2.dummy
where a1_1.a != a1_2.a;
```

Output (with above snippet):

```
+-----+-----+
|  A  | A_1 |
+-----+-----+
| efg | abc |
| abc | efg |
+-----+-----+
```

Desired output:

```
+-----+-----+
|  A  | A_1 |
+-----+-----+
| efg | abc |
+-----+-----+
```

Is there a way to get pairs (rather than permutations above)?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `<`:

```
select a1_1.a, a1_2.a
from a1 a1_1 join
     a1 a1_2
     on a1_1.dummy = a1_2.dummy and
        a1_1.a < a1_2.a;
```